# I don't get the answer for why debug assertion failed on my program

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very new in the coding community. This is my first year and I have never been told about debug assertion errors. I've tried googling for several solutions but I can't seem to relate them to my code and I failed to find the answer.

I would love to receive some help about 'Debug Assertion Failed. Expression: String subscript out of range.'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Declaring variables and arrays
int no_of_subs;

int main ()
{
    cout << " Please enter the number of subjects \n \n ";
    cin >> no_of_subs;

// Local Variable
string grade;

for (int i=1; i <= no_of_subs; i++)
    for (int counterSubs = 0; counterSubs < no_of_subs; counterSubs++)
    {
        cout << " Please enter the grade obtained for each subject \n \n "
            << i++ << " : ";
        cin >> grade [counterSubs];
    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
```

}

My code is about GPA. I want to make an array that stores the grade obtained by the student for each subject. I was expecting the output as below:

"Please enter the grade for each subject

1: *user inputs the Grade*
2:

Comment: `for (int i=1; i <= no_of_subs; i++)` Your indexing is off by one. Indices go from `0` to `no_of_subs - 1`.

Comment: also, you are incrementing `i` twice (in the first for line and within inner loop): I doubt this is what you really want to do.

Comment: above comment solves it. In the future consider using a debugger, that would bring you straight where the error is, you lucky user of `string` type.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Does the `string` type promise to do this instead of just crash when accessing non-existent indexes?

Comment: @Omnifarious, just guessing `Debug Assertion Failed. Expression: String subscript out of range` sounds good enough to me :) It may depend on the implementation and/or debug/optimization options. And for instance, it doesn't work with `vector` unless you use `.at()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with this program. You appear to be trying to index starting with one instead of 0. Also, you appear to be trying to read grades into an empty string and setting the non-existent elements of this empty string to the grades being read in. Also, you are incrementing `i` both in your `for` statement and when you read in your grade, which I do not think is what you want.

I think you have some very fundamental misunderstandings here. I also suspect you are trying to do homework, so I leave it to your TAs and yourself to correct these.

The debug assertion error you are getting is something that I think your implementation is doing. Normally this program would just crash. But because you are trying to access non-existent elements of a string, your implementation may have some helpful code in it that complains instead of crashing. So, this is not a standard part of C++, and not something that can be counted on to happen. I am quite surprised your implementation is doing it.

Comment: VS on debug has out of range guards, not too surprising to see.